# Dynamically generated elements don't captures events

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to attach onclick events to elements created dynamically, but only the last element captures the event, ... why?

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head><title>Error</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load",function(e) {
            var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
            for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
                wrapper.innerHTML += "<p><textarea id='text" + i + "'></textarea></p>";
                text = document.getElementById("text" + i);
                text.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
                    this.innerHTML = this.id;
                },false);
            }
        },false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, my english is very bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in every iteration of the loop, you're completely destroying all the nodes inside `wrapper` when you do `wrapper.innerHTML += ...`.

I'm not crazy about `.innerHTML` as a means of DOM manipulation, but if you must, then use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(e) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
        wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p><textarea id='text" + i + "'></textarea></p>");
        var text = document.getElementById("text" + i);
        text.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            this.innerHTML = this.id;
        },false);
    }
},false);
```

This will insert new nodes parsed from the HTML you provide at the `"beforeend"` position instead of destroying and rebuilding the content every time.

---

Nicer would be to use DOM creation methods.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(e) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
        var text = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
                          .appendChild(document.createElement("textarea"));
        text.id="text" + i;
        text.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            this.innerHTML = this.id;
        },false);
    }
},false);
```

Comment: thank you, I spent all the day with this problem, ...I'm starting with js

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that browser creates dom objects from innerHTML and after that you add a listener to that dom element. When you set new innerHTML value browser recreates the dom and your listeners dies with that old dom elements.
So you need to create dom first then add the listeners.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
    wrapper.innerHTML += "<p><textarea id='text" + i + "'></textarea></p>";
}
for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
    text = document.getElementById("text" + i);
    text.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        this.innerHTML = this.id;
    },false);
}
```